# How to Activate and deactivate a flow using metadataService?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

i want to fetch flows and provide a button to activate and deactivate the flow, i was able to fetch a flow but unable to activate and deactivate it.

Comment: I think it is able to do that using Metadata API after version 34 or so.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flowdefinition.htm

> To activate a flow, modify the metadata object and set the activeVersionNumber to the version number to activate. To deactivate an active flow version, set the activeVersionNumber to 0 (zero) or omit the value.