# Deleting a Flow via CI/CD - how?

Tags: visual-workflow, cicd, mdapideploy

I have a flow that was deployed to multiple production orgs via mdapi CI/CD process. This flow updates 2 fields. Turns out this was not a solution and I now need to delete all 3(the flow + the 2 fields). I can't delete the fields without first deleting the flow, and herein lies my problem. How do I delete a flow using my deploy process?

If I create a new pull request that has a destructive command to delete the flow, it fails to do so - one can't delete an active flow. So I thought to first deploy a change setting the `<Status>Active</Status>` to `<Status>Draft</Status>`, but it doesn't work - it doesn't change the Active to Draft so the Flow remains Active.

I've tried to alter the Flow to a dud one, but the status there is `<Status>InvalidDraft</Status>`, and just leaves the original Active one. So if use this method, I have to actually create a valid dud flow. Seems crazy.

Is there any way to deactivate a flow (without doing it manually in the orgs) via a deploy process ***without using FlowDefinition***? Because I'm hoping when it's deactivated I can delete it!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm), it looks like you should be able to set the status to Obsolete, which should deactivate the flow and allow you to subsequently delete it.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't do it - it just ignores the update and keeps the current Active one :(. What I had to do in the end was create a new dummy version with a dud assignment (to make it a valid flow), deploy that as Active v2, then I could delete v1 in the destructive process (flowname-1), Then I could delete the 2 fields that were referenced in the old v1. What a pain. Now I have a dud flow sitting there until SF allows us to deactivate a flow via deploy.

Comment: @Irene I wonder if that's an oversight? I'll experiment.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately the current documentation that states you can deactivate via setting the Status attribute on the Flow metadata is not accurate. You have experienced this, and my org has also just experienced the same where we first tried via setting the Status attribute, had no success, and then had to use a Flow Definition with Version 0 to successfully deactivate a flow via Metadata Deployment along the lines of this answer: [How to Activate and deactivate a flow using metadataService?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214216/how-to-activate-and-deactivate-a-flow-using-metadataservice)